# Add value to select List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

this is my select list:

```
ViewBag.gov = new SelectList(entity.gouvernerat, "Idgov", "Nomg");
```

And this is how i calld it in my view :

```
 <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.gov, ViewBag.gov as SelectList) %>
```

So i'm wondring how to add Value to this DropdownList without adding it into my DateBase Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following overload to provide a default value:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.gov, 
    ViewBag.gov as SelectList,
    "-- select a value --"
) %>
```

Comment: and then in my action i should put `if (model.gov != null)`

Comment: @Chlebta, why do you need to put something like this? What are you trying to achieve? If you want to ensure that the user selected some value other than the default one in the dropdown simply decorate your `gov` property with the `[Required]` attribute and inside your controller action test `if (ModelState.IsValid)`. Obviously the `gov` property must be a nullable reference type. It won't work with value types.

Comment: gov it's search option so it's not required if user selected a value then i will inculde wehre for this value gov.

Answer (score 3):

Something like that, I think

```
var list = new SelectList(entity.gouvernerat, "Idgov", "Nomg").ToList();
list.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "<MyText>", Value = "0" }));
ViewBag.gov=list;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new SelectList(entity.gouvernerat, "Idgov", "Nomg");
ListItem li = new ListItem(value, value);
list.items.add(li);
ViewBag.gov = list;
```

Comment: lisr.Items.add(li) dosn't work (add dosn't exist in Items context)